# What is difference between "get off" and “get out of”?

Tags: differences

What is the difference when you say “get off” and “get out of”?

Comment: Context, please. An example sentence, please. Your own research, please.

Comment: "Get off my foot!"  "I sure hope I can get out of doing the dishes!"  You can't tell the difference??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both mean exiting.

For example, *Get off* is (formally) exiting a public transport as in

*Get off the bus at the next stop.*

*Get out* is something informal, for example to exit your own transport as in

*Get out of the car once I tell you to.*

For more help, see [this](https://hinative.com/en-US/questions/145105).

Comment: There are many possible meanings. See [*get off*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+off) vs [*get out off*](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/get+out+of). Please avoid answering off-topic questions.

Comment: You're explanation works fine for planes, trains, and automobiles, but these don't mean the same thing: _Get out of my refrigerator_ vs. _Get off my refrigerator_. Also, I might exclaim, "Get off my lawn!" or "Get out of my yard!" but I probably wouldn't say "Get off my yard!" or "Get out of my lawn!"